# Cambiar elementos de una select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una select con options donde salen unos nombres en ingles. Estoy tratando de recorrerlo e ir cambiandolo empleando JQuery. Pero no logro hacerlo... Algun aayuda

```js
var length = $('select[name=day]').children('option').length;
for (i=0; i<length; i++){
    $("select[name=day]").val(i).change("Lunes");            
}
```

```html
<select name="day">
 <option value="" selected>Select</option>
 <option value="monday">Monday</option>
 <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
 <option value="friday">Friday</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías obtener las opciones del select en el selector y recorrerlas cada una. Para cambiar el texto, usas la función `text()` y en el caso de que quieras cambiar el valor usa la función `val()`

```
  $('select[name=day] > option').each(function(index, element){
      $(element).text('lunes');
  });
```

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el método [each() de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```js
var $options = $('select[name=day]').children('option');
   
$options.each(function(){
    $(this).text("lunes");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="day">
 <option value="" selected>Select</option>
 <option value="monday">Monday</option>
 <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
 <option value="friday">Friday</option>
</select>
```